# Tensorflow2.4, model_main_tf2.py, chechpoint problem during training

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection, tensorflow2

I follow the Gilbert Tunner tutorial to Object Detection using Tensorflow 2, but I have this error during the training with `model_main_ft2.py`:

Traceback (most recent call last):

> File "model_main_tf2.py", line 113, in 
> tf.compat.v1.app.run()   File "C:\Users\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\app.py",
> line 40, in run
> _run(main=main, argv=argv, flags_parser=_parse_flags_tolerate_undef)   File
> "C:\Users\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow2\lib\site-packages\absl\app.py",
> line 300, in run
> _run_main(main, args)   File "C:\Users\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow2\lib\site-packages\absl\app.py",
> line 251, in _run_main
> sys.exit(main(argv))   File "model_main_tf2.py", line 110, in main
> record_summaries=FLAGS.record_summaries)   File "C:\Users\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow2\lib\site-packages\object_detection\model_lib_v2.py",
> line 566, in train_loop
> unpad_groundtruth_tensors)   File "C:\Users\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow2\lib\site-packages\object_detection\model_lib_v2.py",
> line 339, in load_fine_tune_checkpoint
> if not is_object_based_checkpoint(checkpoint_path):   File "C:\Users\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow2\lib\site-packages\object_detection\model_lib_v2.py",
> line 302, in is_object_based_checkpoint
> var_names = [var[0] for var in tf.train.list_variables(checkpoint_path)]   File
> "C:\Users\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\checkpoint_utils.py",
> line 112, in list_variables
> reader = load_checkpoint(ckpt_dir_or_file)   File "C:\Users\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\checkpoint_utils.py",
> line 67, in load_checkpoint
> return py_checkpoint_reader.NewCheckpointReader(filename)   File "C:\Users\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\py_checkpoint_reader.py",
> line 99, in NewCheckpointReader
> error_translator(e)   File "C:\Users\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\py_checkpoint_reader.py",
> line 35, in error_translator
> raise errors_impl.NotFoundError(None, None, error_message) tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: Unsuccessful
> TensorSliceReader constructor: Failed to find any matching files for
> C:/Users/Desktop/Tutorial/models/research/object_detection/efficientdet_d0_coco17_tpu-32/chechpoint/ckpt-0

I've create `efficientdet_d0_coco17_tpu-32` folder inside object detection folder, downloading and unzipping my model. I've already modify the model inside training folder adding a checkpoint PATH.

Comment: Please update your question with the command you are using to run and also the folder structure

Comment: I fix it! The error was an image with size over the efficentdet d0 size request!!

Answer (score 0):

From comments

> The error was an image with size over the `efficentdetd0` size request (paraphrased from dons21)